# Combinatorial techniques, methods, and ideas in (“undergraduate”) real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, soft-question, big-list

This question is dual to *[Probabilistic techniques, methods, and ideas in ("undergraduate") real analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075772/probabilistic-techniques-methods-and-ideas-in-undergraduate-real-analysis)*: I would like to collect some examples of **combinatorial** arguments to undergraduate (so to say) real analysis (that is, to calculus problems).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems the following.

*Proposition.* Each sequence of real numbers contains a monotonic subsequence.

*Proof.* Let $\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Consider the following 2-coloring of the edges of the graph $K_{\Bbb N}$ (that is the graph whose vertices are natural numbers and each two different vertices are joined by an edge). Let $m<n$ be natural numbers. Color an edge which joins vertices $m$ and $n$ red if $a_m\le a_n$ and green otherwise. [Infinite Ramsey Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey's_theorem#Infinite_Ramsey_theorem) implies that there exists an infinite subset $M$ of $\Bbb N$ such that all edges which join vertices of $M$ have the same color. Then the sequence $\{a_n:n\in M\}$ is a monotonic subsequence of the sequence $\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$.$\square$

Comment: Good. Thank you, Alex.