# Integral of the square of a floor function in an infinite sum

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Consider the given integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lfloor 2^n x\rfloor}{3^n})^2 \,dx
$$
Please suggest how to approach this problem.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but you need to tell us what you have tried before we can help you.

Comment: I couldn't really do anything with it. That's why I felt stuck.

Comment: You should try anything, even if it doesn't work. Alternatively, if you really have no idea where to start, it would at least be a good idea to tell us where you found this integral.$\tag*{}$ If you want a hint about where to start, expand the square into a double-series, swap the double-series and integral, and try integrating each term. This may or may not lead to a solution.

Comment: Alright, I will try that and if I don't succeed I'll ask again. Thanks!

Comment: Attempt a graphical representation of the function under the integral sign (integrand).

Comment: Please stop posting [duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642139/question-from-mit-integration-bee-2023-final-evaluate-int1-0-sum-infty-n) *(and provide the source!)*